how can I connect multiple lighting wires to one power supply wire
I have a 5 pendant light fixture where each pendant has a three wires: one labeled N, one labeled E and one labeled L.  These need to be connected to black power wire, the white wire and the ground of the house wiring.  How do I do this?

What's the problem, exactly? Are you unfamiliar with the devices use to connect wires? What part of the world are you in? If you're that new to house wiring I highly recommend doing some reading before diving in. Your safety depends on it.

@crip659, answers go down there. Flagged. Again.

On the one hand, black, white, ground indicates US/Canada.
On the other hand, L, N, E indicates some other area of the world (particularly E for Earth instead of G for Ground) and/or unlisted junk.
Anything permanently installed in the US or Canada needs to have an appropriate listing from an organization such as UL or ETL. There are some exceptions for special situations, normally worked out with your local electrical inspector. But for ordinary lighting fixtures you really need UL or ETL or comparable. CE can be meaningful in some situations and locations, but generally means nothing in the US. FCC is about radio emissions/interference and has nothing to do with electrical safety. TM is trademark. Etc. Basically if you don't see UL or ETL or another mark that you know is from an NRTL, do not hardwire it into your electrical system.
Assuming for the moment that this is legitimate equipment listed by UL or ETL but they kept the "worldwide" labels of N, E, L, the solution is:

Connect all L together and to the black wire.
Connect all N together and to the white wire.
Connect all E together and to the bare or green ground wire or to a properly grounded metal box.

